# How can "www.omgwtflol.us" post in my name?!

Tags: sharing, facebook-sharer

After following (only once and only one click) a link posted from a friend, from www.omgwtflol.com  posts like "Ionut Bigu shared a link via Pranker or Mega LOL " or "Ionut Bigu voted for" appear to my timeline and to all my friens. Ho can they do that in my name?  in specially after reporting them as spam?! How do I permanently remove this A.s h...s from my facebook page?

Comment: This isn't facebook support. Also, if you seriously visited that URL, you deserve what you got.

Comment: 1. Yes indeed maybe I deserve it but I had  accessed  that link only once, not having heard about them  before... (I am not a facebook maniac nor  an addicted)  and regarding facebook support

Comment: - it is useless... - I tried once - When I created my account - My surename isn't Bigu,  It si Big and I sent them my ID card but nobody even bothered to responded so why would they bother now, Besides I found Stackoverflow.com looking for facebook contact forms. Sorry to waist your time. Alexis 'ZeNy' Bize thank for your reply ; problem solved

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to remove the app from: http://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications, and finally block it.